# Framework for Cumulative Calculations in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery-m

## Background

I found myself needing some M equivalent of [`cumsum()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/cumsum.html) from [R](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/r/info).  After some frustrating research, I discovered that there is little support for cumulative operations in PowerQuery.

I set out to implement a function for cumulative summation, but I soon realized this approach could be generalized to *any* list function like [`List.Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/list-sum).  Borrowing [function factories](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html) from R, I propose a convenient and extensible solution in M.

## Solution

### `Function_AsCumulative()`

This is a function factory, and it generates the cumulative version of a `function`.

```m
let Function_AsCumulative = (
    // The function itself, of the form 'function(list, ...)'.
    function as function
) as function =>
    // Generate the cumulative function.
    (
        // The list over which to cumulatively invoke the function.
        list as list,
        
        // Further arguments ('...') passed to 'function(list, ...)'.
        optional args as nullable list
    ) as list =>
        let
            // Default to no arguments.
            args = if args = null then
                {}
            else
                args,
            
            // Short-circuit for an empty list... 
            result = if List.IsEmpty(list) then
                {}
                
            // ...and otherwise accumulate the values for each subset.
            else
                let
                    // Take every subset S_k = {l_1, 1_2, ..., l_k}
                    // of the list L = {l_1, l_2, ..., l_k, ..., l_n}...
                    count = List.Count(list),
                    indices = List.Numbers(1, count, 1),
                    accumulation = List.Transform(indices, each Function.Invoke(
                        
                    // ...and compile its return value x_k = function(S_k, ...).
                        function, List.Combine({{List.FirstN(list, _)}, args})
                    //  ^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^
                    //  function (                        S_k         ,  ... )
                    ))
                in
                    accumulation
        in
            result
in
    Function_AsCumulative
```

### `Function_InvokeCumulative()`

This invokes a `function` cumulatively over a `list`.

```m
let Function_InvokeCumulative = (
    // The list over which to cumulatively invoke the function.
    list as list,
    
    // The function itself, of the form 'function(list, ...)'.
    function as function,
    
    // Further arguments ('...') passed to 'function(list, ...)'.
    optional args as nullable list
) as list =>
    let
        // Generate the cumulative version of the function.
        cFun = Function_AsCumulative(function),
        
        // Invoke the cumulative function to obtain the cumulative result.
        result = cFun(list, args)
    in
        result
in
    Function_InvokeCumulative
```

### Note

If the original `function` accepts further arguments (`...`) beyond the `list`, then those further arguments may be passed as a `list` (`{...}`) to the `args` parameter.  This `args` parameter is found both in `Function_InvokeCumulative()` itself, and also in any cumulative `function` *generated by* `Function_AsCumulative()`.

## Application

One can generate the function `List_CumulativeSum()` by invoking `Function_AsCumulative()` on [`List.Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/list-sum):

```m
List_CumulativeSum = Function_AsCumulative(List.Sum)
```

So calling

```m
List_CumulativeSum({1..10})
```

is equivalent to calling

```m
Function_InvokeCumulative(List.Sum, {1..10})
```

and it returns the following `list`:

```
{1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55}
```

---

## Alternative

Some time ago I posted an alternative solution, which should run in **()** rather than **(²)** time, but which is restricted to binary operations (◦) that obey the [generalized associative law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Generalized_associative_law):

(((⋯((₁ ◦ ₂) ◦ ₃) ◦ ⋯) ◦ ₙ₋₂) ◦ ₙ₋₁) ◦ ₙ

= (₁ ◦ ₂ ◦ ₃ ◦ ⋯ ◦ ₙ₋₂ ◦ ₙ₋₁) ◦ ₙ

= ₁ ◦ ₂ ◦ ₃ ◦ ⋯ ◦ ₙ₋₂ ◦ ₙ₋₁ ◦ ₙ.

### Workhorses

The function `Function_MakeCumulative()` is a function factory.  It accepts a `function` as input, and returns a cumulative version of that `function`, of the form `Fun(list, args, skip)`:

```m
Function_MakeCumulative = (
    // The function itself, of the form 'Fun(x, y, ...)'.
    function as function,

    // The default seed for when we do not skip.
    optional default as nullable any
) as function =>
    // Generate the cumulative function.
    (
        list as list,
        optional skip as nullable logical,
        optional args as nullable list
    ) as list =>
        let
            // Default 'skip' to positive ('true').
            skip = if skip = null then
                true
            else
                skip,
            
            // Default 'args' to none ('{}').
            args = if args = null then
                {}
            else
                args,
            
            // Assemble a list with the running values.
            result = if skip = true then
                // When skipping, use the first element and accumulate afterwards.
                List.Accumulate(
                    List.RemoveFirstN(list, 1),
                    {List.First(list, {})},
                    (state, current) => List.Combine({
                        state, {
                        Function.Invoke(function, List.Combine({
                            {List.Last(state, {})},
                            {current},
                            args
                        }))
                    }})
                )
            else
                // When not skipping, start with the default and accumulate everything.
                List.Accumulate(
                    list,
                    {},
                    (state, current) => List.Combine({state, {
                        Function.Invoke(function, List.Combine({
                            {List.Last(state, default)},
                            {current},
                            args
                        }))
                    }})
                )
        in
            result
```

The function `Function_InvokeCumulative()` accepts a `function` and a `list` as input, and invokes that `function` cumulatively over the `list`.

```m
Function_InvokeCumulative = (
    // The list over which to cumulatively invoke the function.
    list as list,

    // The function itself, of the form 'Fun(x, y, ...)'.
    function as function,

    // Should the first value be the first element ('true') in the list, as is; or should
    // we generate it ('false') by calling the function on that element and some seed?
    optional skip as nullable logical,

    // The default seed for when we do not skip.
    optional default as nullable any,
    
    // Further arguments ('...') passed to 'Fun(x, y, ...)'.
    optional args as nullable list
) as list =>
    let
        // Default 'skip' to affirmative ('true').
        skip = if skip = null then
            true
        else
            skip,
        
        // Default 'args' to none ('{}').
        args = if args = null then
            {}
        else
            args,
        
        // Generate the cumulative version of the function.
        cFun = Function_MakeCumulative(function, default),

        // Invoke the cumulative function to obtain the cumulative result.
        result = cFun(list, skip, args)
    in
        result
```

#### Note

The first element of the output `list` may be generated in one of two ways.

- When `skip` is `true` by default, then the first element is simply
  taken "as is" from the input `list`.
- When `skip` is `false`, then the first element is taken from the
  input `list`, and next the `function` is invoked with that element
  and the `default` as its operands.

When cumulatively performing `+` on a list `{1,2,3}`, the former approach will use `1` as the first element; while the latter will use `0 + 1`, where `0` is the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for `+`.

### Application

Here I define a function `Op_Sum()`, which functionally implements the summation operation (`+`).  More generally, `Op_Sum()` hails from the `Op_*()` family, which functionally implements various binary operations.

```m
Op_Sum = (x, y) =>
    x + y
```

I complement `Op_Sum()` with `Id_Sum`, which defines the identity element (`0`) for summation.  More generally, `Id_Sum` hails from the `Id_*` family, which defines the identity elements for various operations.

```m
Id_Sum = 0
```

Finally, I generate a function `Cumulative_Sum()` by invoking `Function_MakeCumulative()` on `Op_Sum()` with `Id_Sum`:

```m
Cumulative_Sum = Function_MakeCumulative(Op_Sum, Id_Sum)
```

So calling

```m
Cumulative_Sum({1..10})
```

is equivalent to calling

```m
Function_InvokeCumulative((x, y) => x + y, {1..10})
```

and it returns the following `list`:

```
{1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55}
```

Comment: In excel this is called SCAN() which takes a lambda and an array to reduce using an accumulator, but unlike the REDUCE function it will output intermediate steps like you have. So maybe stick with that naming convention for consistency. My worry with this is that PQ is not "meant" to perform row-wise functions as they can't be vectorised so it will probably be quite slow and most usecases you should prefer some other approach that is more idiomatic

Comment: @Greedo I actually found a specialized solution with [`List.Accumulate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/list-accumulate) that should run in () time, rather than the (²) here. Unfortunately, it only works for a binary operation ◦ (like `+`) that obeys the [generalized associative law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Generalized_associative_law): (((⋯((₁ ◦ ₂) ◦ ₃) ◦ ⋯) ◦ ₙ₋₂) ◦ ₙ₋₁) ◦ ₙ = (₁ ◦ ₂ ◦ ₃ ◦ ⋯ ◦ ₙ₋₂ ◦ ₙ₋₁) ◦ ₙ = ₁ ◦ ₂ ◦ ₃ ◦ ⋯ ◦ ₙ₋₂ ◦ ₙ₋₁ ◦ ₙ. It obviously fails when (say) you wish to take a cumulative _average_.

Comment: @Greedo I have [appended](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/288474/timeline#history_4e0d4816-ae7a-4855-a548-fcc08cefbaf2) that older, specialized solution.